# How to authenticate user by custom model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to authenticate user with my custom model but on login page user is logged in only by Django admin credential. All I wanna do is to authenticate user by my custom model

Please help with this code I am not able to create user authentication using custom model.

Here is the models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField`

#Create your models here.

    class registerdata(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
        phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    #here is views.py of app
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse 
    from django.contrib import messages`
    from .models import registerdata
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
    from django.contrib.auth import logout`
    # Create your views here.
    def login(request):
        #code for checking authentication 
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.POST)
            username=request.POST.get("username")
            password=request.POST.get("password")
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                print('auth pass')
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('chats')
            else:
                print('auth fail')
                messages.info(request,"invalid credentials")
                return redirect('loginpage')
        return render(request,'login.html')
    def Register(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            name = request.POST.get('name', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            phone = request.POST.get('phone', '')
            password= request.POST.get('password','')
            Register = registerdata(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, password=password)
            Register.save()
            return redirect('loginpage')  
        return render(request, 'register.html')
    def chats(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logout(request)
            return render(request,'chats.html')
        else :
            return redirect('loginpage')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.chats, name='chats'),
        path('login/', views.login, name='loginpage'),
        path('Register/', views.Register, name='Register'),
    ]
```

Comment: Django normally hashes passwords, that is why one often writes a custom user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords

Answer (score 0):

problem is your custom user model is not exactly a django custom user but just a normal model with table in the database , and you can't use any of django auth related functionalities on your model. take a look at this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) about how you should implement a custom user model